# Open source library or class that punches through NAT/Firewalls for P2P data transfer

Tags: c#, .net, networking, sockets

I'm looking for some C#/.NET library that I can use to do some NAT-Punching for multi-player game development. Using a central server to establish initial connection is OK, but ideally connections would drop into p2p mode after initial communication with server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with P2P data transfer in .NET please take a look at [Mono Torrent](http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/monotorrent) that's an open source implementation of the BitTorrent protocol.

You can either embed the whole Mono Torrent library and use BitTorrent as your underlying protocol or take the relevant parts of it for your own project. The library has a very liberal license (MIT/X11) that allows embedding.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look into it. What I'm really lookin for is some way to punch through firewalls and NAT routers. It is too comlicated to expect users to open ports on their firewall to make my application work.